# VB-If, Else,Then...I think

Tags: vb.net

Well hi im totally new to vb i just started this morning...I know nothing
Im trying to make a search engine but im having some trouble, this is what i have so far

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please make an input")
    End If

     TextBox1.Text = "message" Then
    MsgBox("Yaw searcher is now searching for your input")
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    MsgBox("File Found,redirecting to search results")
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + _
        TextBox1.Text + _
    "%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i65l3j69i60.3515j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8")
```

Im trying to make it so that if any message is entered the program would come up and say

```
    MsgBox("Yaw searcher is now searching for your input")
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    MsgBox("File Found,redirecting to search results")
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + _
        TextBox1.Text + _
    "%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i65l3j69i60.3515j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8")
```

if not it says pelase make an imput...ive got that part but cant get the last part thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the additional `if` check @prospector [uses in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27790133/4302070) as [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will cover both scenarios (`null`, or in VB.NET's case `Nothing`, and `String.Empty`):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'check if the textbox content is empty or null
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("You need to enter something to search for!")
    'if not empty or null, search google for that keyword instead
    Else
        MsgBox("Yaw searcher is now searching for your input")
        MsgBox("File Found,redirecting to search results")
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Bear in mind that `MsgBox("File Found,redirecting to search results")` isn't really needed or informative, as the actual google search starts in the browser when you call `Process.Start`.

In it's simplest form, here is the `If-Then-Else` syntax in VB.NET:

```
If SomeCondition Then
    DoSomething()
ElseIf SomeOtherCondition Then
    DoSomethingElse()
Else
    DoSomethingIrrelevant()
End If
```

An example from MSDN's ["If...Then...Else Statement (Visual Basic)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) (slightly modified):

```
Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim message As String 

If count = 0 Then
    'this will only run if count = 0 
    message = "There are no items." 
ElseIf count = 1 Then
    'this will only run if count = 1
    message = "There is 1 item." 
ElseIf count = 2 Then
    'this will only run if count = 2
    message = "There are 2 items."
Else
    'this will only run if count has any value other than 0, 1 or 2
    message = "There are more than 2 items or less than 0 items." 
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used your method since i understood it more... also thank you for showing me the IsNullOrEmpty code i didnt know that this code even existed. Thanks again and i hope you will be able to help me in the future, as i said before im a beginner just started 8 hours ago ty :p

Bye

Answer (score 0):

You should use If, Else, then End If

[**This Link will help you understand**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/if-vbnet)

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please make an input")
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "message" Then
           MsgBox("Yaw searcher is now searching for your input")
           Timer1.Enabled = True
           MsgBox("File Found,redirecting to search results")
           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + TextBox1.Text + "%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i65l3j69i60.3515j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8")

    Else
        MsgBox("input is not message or blank")
    End If
```

Comment: Hey thankyou for your answeri will try to furthere my studies with the if,else and end if commands since im a total noob... lol thanks tho i only didnt use this cause i didnt understand it really thanks for the help hope u will be able to continue helping me